# Can someone resize this image so it is not blury in insta pfp

Tags: resize, information-graphics

[image]

Please Resize image so not blury in insta pfp

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  The image is not blurry. Anyway, I'm voting to close this question because requests for free work are off-topic. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -4):

There is a proverb: **"give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"**

StackExchange leans a lot more towards dicussions which can be reapplied over and over again, feeding for a lifetime.

This question is very much asking for one fish. If StackExchange was the place for such requests, the majority of posts would be along these lines being demands for one fish, and the serious lifetime discussion would go elsewhere.

Here is your request, it is what you asked. But this is not where you should have asked it. Maybe there is a subreddit for photoshop requests?

[image: Resized to Instagram dimensions]

Comment: Some days it seems easier to give a man a fish; other days, maybe one would feel like teaching. Today, I'm more inclined to just point at the river & shrug.

Comment: Although informative, this is not really an answer. Perhaps next time just add as a comment?

Comment: @Luciano understood and agreed. Will address as suggested in the future.